# Firebase cost for using verifyIdToken in firebase http functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

Does Validate IdToken in backend using firebase-admin cost money? or will it contribute towards document count?

```
getAuth()
  .verifyIdToken(idToken)
  .then((decodedToken) => {
    const uid = decodedToken.uid;
    // ...
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // Handle error
  })

;
```

Other information = I am using express js app as firebase http function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does Validate IdToken in backend using firebase-admin cost money?

No, not directly.

> or will it contribute towards document count?

No, it has nothing at all to do with Firestore data.

I suggest reviewing the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/pricing) for how Firebase products are billed.  Everything you need to know is there.  Firebase Auth doesn't cost anything at all.  Cloud Functions only charges for execution time and data sent.  The only thing that the Firebase Admin SDK will do to the cost of your function is add a few milliseconds of execution time.